Make Html5 Canvas progress bar to circle from semi circle
I am creating one progress bar using Html5 Canvas, Where i need to show the progress bar based on provided value. Now user set some value and based on it the progress bar should complete the progress.
I have found some code from google and tried to implement the same, But since I don't have much idea about the Html5 Canvas. Need some of your help to complete the same.
The current code is showing the progress as semi circle till 45 degree only.
below are the screenshot FYR.



var
  canv = document.getElementById('canv'),
  ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

canv.width = 400;
canv.height = 400;

var
  center_x = canv.width / 2,
  center_y = canv.height + 50,
  radius = 150;

ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#492528';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, 0, Math.PI, true);
//ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, Math.PI + 0.2, true);
ctx.stroke();

var
  l_ = -2.93,
  l_t = -2.3,
  simpleAnimationTimer = setInterval(function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#301618';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, l_, Math.PI, true);
    ctx.lineTo(center_x - 10, center_y);
    //ctx.lineTo(center_x, center_y - 20);
    ctx.fill();

    var
      grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(center_x, center_y, 50, center_x, center_y, radius);

    // grad.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(246,178,86, 0.2)');
    // grad.addColorStop(0.3, 'rgba(246,178,86, 0.1)');
    // grad.addColorStop(.5, 'rgba(45, 14, 16, 0.5)');
    grad.addColorStop(1, '#53301A');
    grad.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(90, 14, 16, 1)');

    ctx.fillStyle = grad;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, l_, Math.PI + 0.2, true);
    ctx.lineTo(center_x - 20, center_y);
    ctx.lineTo(center_x, center_y - 40);
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.lineWidth = 15;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#F7B349';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, l_, Math.PI + 0.2, true);
    ctx.stroke();

    l_ += .01;
    if (l_ > -2.30) {
      clearInterval(simpleAnimationTimer);
    }
  }, 20);

function drawTick(angle, from, to) {
  var
    angle = angle, // 168 is start
    xs = center_x + radius * Math.cos(-angle * Math.PI) * from,
    ys = center_y + radius * Math.sin(-angle * Math.PI) * from,
    xe = center_x + radius * Math.cos(-angle * Math.PI) * to,
    ye = center_y + radius * Math.sin(-angle * Math.PI) * to;

  ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#8A6047';

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(xs, ys);
  ctx.lineTo(xe, ye);
  ctx.stroke();
}

// first level outer ticks
for (i = 0; i < 157; i++) {
  drawTick(168 - i * 1, 1.1, 1.06);
}

// dots
for (i = 0; i < 157; i++) {
  drawTick(168 - i * 1, 1.25, 1.255);
}

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#603738';

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius + 55, -0.2, Math.PI + 0.2, true);
ctx.stroke();

// first level outer ticks
for (i = 0; i < 58; i++) {
  drawTick(167 - i * 2.7, 1.3, 1.35);
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
<canvas id="canv">Your browser not support canvas.</canvas>




What's l_ and l_t? That's a bad naming convention. And you said, the semi circle is upto 45 degrees now. So what do you want ?

As I have studied, changing the if condition for clearTimeout() does some work. if( l_ > -1.30 )     {       clearInterval(simpleAnimationTimer);     }   }, 20);
It creates a more extendend semi circle.

I don't see 45deg anywhere when I run your code. Could you explain a bit more exactly what you want to achieve?

@M.Riyan: As i have mention in the question, I have taken this code from some of the website. I am a beginner about the canvas.

@AHaworth: I have attached one screenshot where progress bar is showing till 45 degree only. Here i need 2 things: a. This semi circle has to be show as a complete circle b. progress bar show completely based on some provided number. e.g: user put any number like 100, 200 etc and based on it the progress bar should complete.

check https://jsfiddle.net/0m2qfoeu/

My point was that that is not 45deg. It's important because you are trying to show the user a measurement. And I'm not clear what the units are.

@AHaworth: As i have mentioned before, I have took this code from some of other website, I am not worry about measurement, I just need the progress bar has to show there as full circle, And progress bar has to complete by user provided value. Also no worry about the units

@ashutoshrathi: Your provided jsfiddle link is most similar to my requirement, Just need here to pass any max value and based on that value progress bar should complete it.

You mentioned that you are a beginner with canvas... Do you know what the parameters are in the arc function: ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, l_, Math.PI + 0.2, true); ??  You needed to understand that before you go asking question on code you taken from some random website

We should consider the progress percentage and compute the angle to generate the arc when we increase progress.
// Draw progress circle
var endAngle = (progress / maxProgress) * 2 * Math.PI - Math.PI / 2;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -Math.PI / 2, endAngle, false);
ctx.strokeStyle = '#4caf50';
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();



var canv = document.getElementById('canv'),
        ctx = canv.getContext('2d');

    canv.width = 400;
    canv.height = 400;

    var center_x = canv.width / 2,
        center_y = canv.height / 2,
        radius = 150;

    ctx.lineWidth = 15;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#492528';

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.stroke();

    var progress = 0;
    var maxProgress = 100; // maximum progress value
    var animationSpeed = 2; // speed of the animation

    var simpleAnimationTimer = setInterval(function() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

      // Draw background circle
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#e6e6e6';
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();

      // Draw progress circle
      var endAngle = (progress / maxProgress) * 2 * Math.PI - Math.PI / 2;
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(center_x, center_y, radius, -Math.PI / 2, endAngle, false);
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#4caf50';
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.closePath();

      // Draw progress text
      ctx.font = '20px Arial';
      ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.fillText(Math.round((progress / maxProgress) * 100) + '%', center_x, center_y);

      progress += animationSpeed;
      if (progress > maxProgress) {
        clearInterval(simpleAnimationTimer);
      }
    }, 50);
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Full Circle Progress Bar</title>
  <style>
    canvas {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id="canv"></canvas>
</body>
</html>



check Fiddle: jsfiddle.net/0m2qfoeu.

If you are a beginner you needed the basics of arc before you can make any progress:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc
arc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle, counterclockwise)

The arc() method creates a circular arc centered at (x, y) with a radius of radius. The path starts at startAngle, ends at endAngle, and travels in the direction given by counterclockwise (defaulting to clockwise).
Parameters
x
The horizontal coordinate of the arc's center.
y
The vertical coordinate of the arc's center.
radius
The arc's radius. Must be positive.
startAngle
The angle at which the arc starts in radians, measured from the positive x-axis.
endAngle
The angle at which the arc ends in radians, measured from the positive x-axis.
counterclockwise Optional
An optional boolean value. If true, draws the arc counter-clockwise between the start and end angles. The default is false (clockwise).

With that clear we can start building some simple animation.
Below we are just moving the angles back and forth to show what we can do.


var canv = document.getElementById('canv')
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d')
var x = canv.width / 2
var y = canv.height / 2
var radius = 60
var angle = 1
var delta = 0.05


setInterval(function() {
  ctx.reset()
  ctx.lineWidth = 15;

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, angle, true);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius - 10, 0, angle);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  ctx.fillText(Math.round(angle), x, y);

  angle += delta;
  if ((angle > Math.PI * 1.9) || (angle < 0.5)) {
    delta *= -1
  }
}, 20);
<canvas id="canv" width=160 height=160></canvas>




We can build another example that given an input it will draw the arc from 0 until that endAngle


var canv = document.getElementById('canv')
var max = document.getElementById('input').value
var ctx = canv.getContext('2d')
var x = canv.width / 2
var y = canv.height / 2
var angle = 0

function draw() {
  angle += 0.01;
  ctx.reset()
  ctx.lineWidth = 15;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
  ctx.arc(x, y, 60, 0, angle);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  ctx.fillText(Math.round(angle*100)/100, x, y);
  
  if (angle > max) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

function inputChange() {
  clearInterval(interval)
  angle = 0
  max = document.getElementById('input').value  
  interval = setInterval(draw, 20)  
}

interval = setInterval(draw, 20)
Goto: 
<input id="input" type="number" value="1.2" min="0" max="6.28" step=0.1  onchange="inputChange()"/>
</br>
<canvas id="canv" width=160 height=160></canvas>



